# How do I optimize the rendering of my HTML not SQL queries?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, performance, optimization, mvc-mini-profiler

So I am using mini-profiler and it gives me some nice stats.

However, one thing I have noticed is that I have gotten a lot of the SQL calls down to a minimum and now the biggest thing is the rendering of the various partials and HTML.

For instance, here are 2 different examples of issues I am facing:

**Mini-Profiler**

```
GET http://localhost:3000/   14.0   +0.0
  Executing action: index    9.5    +9.0
   Rendering: home/index     7.8    +16.0
    Rendering: home/_row     7.9    +22.0
   Rendering: layouts/application    1038.7 +32.0
    Rendering: layouts/_navigation   6.0    +586.0
```

**Development.log**

```
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-05-17 18:00:26 -0500
Processing by HomeController#index as HTML
  Item Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "items".* FROM "items" WHERE "items"."is_approved" = 't'
  ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "tags".* FROM "tags" INNER JOIN "taggings" ON "tags"."id" = "taggings"."tag_id" WHERE "taggings"."taggable_id" = 13 AND "taggings"."taggable_type" = 'Item' AND (taggings.context = 'tags' AND taggings.tagger_id IS NULL)
  Rendered home/_row.html.erb (8.0ms)
  Rendered home/index.html.erb within layouts/application (15.7ms)
  Rendered layouts/_social_media.html.erb (0.5ms)
   (0.4ms)  SELECT items.id FROM "items" 
  ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag Load (0.7ms)  SELECT tags.*, taggings.tags_count AS count FROM "tags" JOIN (SELECT taggings.tag_id, COUNT(taggings.tag_id) AS tags_count FROM "taggings" INNER JOIN items ON items.id = taggings.taggable_id WHERE (taggings.taggable_type = 'Item' AND taggings.context = 'tags') AND (taggings.taggable_id IN(13)) GROUP BY taggings.tag_id HAVING COUNT(taggings.tag_id) > 0) AS taggings ON taggings.tag_id = tags.id ORDER BY count LIMIT 5
  Rendered layouts/_navigation.html.erb (6.1ms)
  Rendered layouts/_site_nav.html.erb (0.6ms)
  Rendered layouts/_messages.html.erb (0.2ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 1069ms (Views: 1066.0ms | ActiveRecord: 2.3ms)
```

The output from Mini-Profiler at the top, shows that the main `application.html.erb` is adding significantly to load time.

Here is another example of another app where the views are the ones that take the most time to render:

```
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-05-17 17:55:01 -0500
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
Processing by HomeController#index as HTML
  Category Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories" LIMIT 6
  Banner Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "banners".* FROM "banners" INNER JOIN "banner_types" ON "banner_types"."id" = "banners"."banner_type_id" WHERE (banner_types.name = 'Featured')
  Banner Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "banners".* FROM "banners" INNER JOIN "banner_types" ON "banner_types"."id" = "banners"."banner_type_id" WHERE (banner_types.name = 'Side')
  Product Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "products".* FROM "products" 
  Vendor Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "vendors".* FROM "vendors" WHERE "vendors"."id" IN (12, 11, 10)
  Vendor Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "vendors".* FROM "vendors" 
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" 
  Rendered home/_popular_products.html.erb (16.1ms)
  Rendered home/_popular_stores.html.erb (2.4ms)
  Rendered home/index.html.erb within layouts/application (26.4ms)
  Piggybak::Sellable Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "sellables".* FROM "sellables" WHERE "sellables"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
  Rendered layouts/_login_nav.html.erb (8.2ms)
  Rendered layouts/_navigation.html.erb (0.8ms)
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "vendors".* FROM "vendors" 
  Rendered layouts/_store_dropdown.html.erb (2.2ms)
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (18.1ms)
  Rendered layouts/_messages.html.erb (0.3ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.9ms)
Completed 200 OK in 242ms (Views: 209.8ms | ActiveRecord: 1.9ms)
```

Granted, this particular time is just `209.8ms`, but it has been as high as `5,000ms` at various loading times.

How can I optimize the rendering of these views & partials? Or what tool can I use to at least figure out what is causing the long load time so I can chip away at it slowly?

Answer (score 1):

You are profiling this in development. Be aware that because of the config.cache_classes setting, you app is reloaded with every request in that environment. Profiling with that setting set to true might give you different (and usually faster) results.

In one of your comments, you mention a `Vendor.all.each` snippet. I would check how long that actually takes. Just wrap it in a `results = Benchmark.measure do` block and see what `results.real` gives you. Let's say it finishes in 50 ms.

You have three options, generally:

- If the 50ms is unsatisfactory, read the partial rendering result from a static file that you regenerate in certain intervals. This can be done by using the rails caching mechanisms or by putting it into a file that you regenerate with a cronjob. Either way, this involves some kind of delay in respect to new vendors that might have been created between intervals.
- Or, if 50ms is fine for you, you can cast them to JSON (which is fast, have a look at https://github.com/ohler55/oj) and as suggested before, pull it with AJAX and render the html with javascript. This has the advantage that the actual rendering of the html is done within the browser. The browser is faster doing it and it usually has less load to cope with.
- If you're unhappy with 50 ms and you can't live with slightly outdated information on your page, you would have to start doing option 2 but without ActiveRecord, so with the mysql ruby adapter directly. Or you make sure that whenever a new Vendor is created or an old one updated, you add JSON into a text column of the respective vendor, perhaps with some after_validation callback. So that you can at least do

  ```
  vendors = Vendor.select(:json_cache).map{|v| v.json_cache}.join(',')
  vendors = "[#{vendors}]"
  render :json => vendors
  ```

  ... not exactly beautiful but blazing fast.

I hope, this is what you wanted to know.

Answer (score 0):

In your second example, I see queries for:

- **All** banners of type "Featured"
- **All** banners of type "Side"
- **All** products
- **All** vendors
- **All** users

If your partials have to iterate through huge collections of objects, it will slow down rendering times considerably.

Watch for iterators that call collections like `Vendor.all.each do |v|`. Model class methods should never be called in the view. Build a collection in the controller of objects you need, then send to the view in an instance variable.

Comment: I usually do that...but in this case, I need to render a collection in a partial that appears in a layout. Which controller do I render that in? The `application_controller`? It's a part of the navigation of the entire site - more or less.

Comment: Database-backed content in a global layout isn't exactly performance-based design. I would extract that out to an ajax request after the page loads. For example, use ajax to hit a messages controller with a user id, which will properly scope and return messages relevant to a user.

Comment: I know it's not performance-based design, but it is business-rules based design. I need to have a `ul` generated from a collection of all the vendors in the system. Can't just throw it in a controller - regardless of how I do the call, i.e. ajax or `Vendor.all.each`, what difference does it make? It will still be making the call for every page load.